# Can only open one file in cpanel with google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cpanel

I have had the following problem when using cpanel iwth google chrome. If I select a file and click 'edit', it opens perfectly. However, if I try it again with another file, nothing happens. I dont have this issue with IE or Mozilla. Does anyone know how I can get cpanel working properly in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know how I can get Chrome
>   working properly on cpanel?

Use the "Report broken webpage" link to send Chrome developers feedback that its broken. If you're using the Dev channel then it *should* get fixed in next release.

Comment: hopefully they take a peak at that

Comment: I had reported couple of pages which were broken as a result of regression, and in the next update they were fixed, even though the sites that I reported weren't exactly high volume, so I think the CPanel problem ought to get fixed :)